# Can't run exe of VideoFrameAnalysis sample app

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I've downloaded , build an ran the VideoFrameAnalysis app inside Visual Studio and it worked fine but when i try to open the exe I get an error and everything closes. 
Is there any solution for that ? Thanks.

Edit:
The wierd thing about this is that is actually does work but I have to open and close it around 4 times. For some unknowen reason it sometimes load and sometimes it doesn't. This is the error I am getting when it doesn't:

[image]

Comment: Which app were you running: BasicConsoleSample or LiveCameraSample?  What was the error?

Comment: Edited and added a screenshot